# I want to download a file using curl request which has an authorization token and then then save the file in the local directory using cypress

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, cypress

What I want to do is make a curl request which has an authorization token as a header and then I want to save the file in the local directory.

I am trying to use request function trying to achieve that but don't have much success of it.

```
it('Testing something', () => { 
cy.request({
   method: 'GET',
   url: 'http://google.com/request',
   auth: {
       bearer: token
   },
   encoding: 'binary'
   }).then((response) => {
       //Validate the response
   });
});

const options = {
  url: `http://google.com/request/download`,
  headers: {
  'Authorization': `Bearer token`
  },
  method: 'GET'
};

const result = https.get(options, response => {
   if(response.statusCode == 200){ 
      const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(destinationFolder);
      request(response.request).pipe(fileStream);
    }
});
});
```

**Problem:** When I run above code the file is not downloaded in the destination folder. I just want to download the file and that will make my test complete. I can download the file using curl request. Is there a way that we can mimic curl request in cypress test.

**Note:** This is a part of cypress test.

Answer (score 1):

Well I figure it out how to acheive it, I am not sure if it is a right approach or not but following is my solution.

I used location in my curl request in order to download the file.

In order to make a curl request from cypress, I used cy.exec :

```
cy.exec{'curl request', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
       if (error) {
          console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
          return;
       }
       if (stderr) {
          console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
          return;
       }
       console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```